# using indexOf to see if there is a match in an object in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof

i want to loop through an array of application numbers to see if there is a match using indexOf.

currently my array looks like..

array:

```
"applications":[  
         "123456",
         "224515",
         "658454",
         "784123"
      ]
```

my controller:

```
$scope.hasApplicationNumber = function (appNo) {
        var applicationsArray = applications;
        return applicationsArray.indexOf(appNo);
      }
```

html:

```
<span ng-if="hasApplicationNumber(784123)">Its a Match!</span>
```

Comment: indexOf doesn't return a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29739/)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.applications = [  
         "123456",
         "224515",
         "658454",
         "784123"
      ];

    $scope.hasApplicationNumber = function (appNo) {
        var res = $scope.applications.filter(item => { return item.indexOf(appNo) != -1; });
        return (res.length) ? true : false;
      }  
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-if="hasApplicationNumber(784123)">Its a Match!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` method returns a `index` of matched `number`. So you should be checking if its greater than -1. Over here you were checking `number` instead of `string`(array member), so before checking you have to convert all array to Number and check otherwise check `appNo` to `string` then find it in an array.

```
$scope.hasApplicationNumber = function (appNo) {
    var applicationsArray = applications;
    //return applicationsArray.indexOf(appNo.toString()) > -1;
    //OR
    //return !!~applicationsArray.map(Number).indexOf(appNo); //then check number
    //OR
    return !!~applicationsArray.indexOf(appNo.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you want to confuse people you can use `return !!~applicationsArray.indexOf(appNo);`

Comment: Bang bang squiggle

Comment: @Joe cool man. That's fantastic, I made an update to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I misunderstanding something? Why not just use Array.prototype.includes?

Disclaimer: This uses ES6 arrow syntax,

```
$scope.hasApplicationNumber = function (appNo) {
    return applicationsArray.map(no => Number(no)).includes(appNo);
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3p4mq9qL/

Edit: Fixed if you want to look by number (when the array is string)

Comment: Worth noting that this uses ES6. A beginner might not know that, and get frustrated trying to use ES6 without Babel or similar.